# how to run a (long) VBA macro in the background while working on an other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I got a use case which I can't figure out a solution to implement and handle it.

My application (first workbook file) code processes a long file. It takes a longtime (say 15 min) and bore the user to wait for the end. The user switches to another workbook (second workbook file) while the process is running.

When the process ends, the application uses a reference to a sheet in the first workbook and miserably fails. How can I handle this situation without hard coding the first file name?

The problem is that a macro runs a process in the a first workbook sheet.
The workbook name is memorized in the application code as following via a global String gsWkbName

```
Public gsWkbName as String
gsWkbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name()
```

the code is executed when the workbook is opened in Workbook_Activate and Workbook_Open before running any meaningful code.

when ever the application need to access a sheet I use the following code

```
Dim wks as Worksheet
With Application.Workbooks(gsWkbName)
  Set wks = .Sheets('somesheet')

End With
```

when the current workbook is not the first workbook I observe multiple bugs.
If the first workbook is the current workbook I don't.
The second workbook has no  running code (by the wat I haven't tried the case where there is running code).

Comment: Optimize the code to decrease run-time.

Comment: How are you referencing the first workbook? Scott has the right idea, you should optimize your code to make it run quicker...

Comment: I guess @ScottHoltzman didn't answer the question :).  Optimizing the code won't remember the first workbook reference.  Passing the workbook reference to a variable and holding that value until the end will.

Comment: @Mast Thank you for the correction. I stated mcve out of habit. I intended to say to provide the code in question which OP failed to do here.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I read the question as "the process takes so long a user may click on a 2nd workbook during run-time".

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I read it as "how do I reference a sheet in the first workbook". I read your comment as "given the information this is about all the help we can offer", so thought I'd also offer the info on handling the reference.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman optimization is not the solution in the short term that would require huge code and architecture rework. As said it does not anwser the question on how to handle a running macro in the background while working on another workbook

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook right optimizing is the better solution. This being said it won't run light speed any ways and I might obtain great optimization but still have to wait few seconds. But switching from one workbook to another seems to be an issue is the context of the application I am developing and I'd like to understand why if you can help of course

Comment: @pascalsautot - **1)** Try `gsWkbName = ThisWorkbook.Name()` That will refer to the workbook running the code, not whatever workbook is active at the time the code runs. **2)** Instruct the users to deal with the wait time. Place a modal form on Excel until your process ends. They can go for coffee or a break or work in another application besides Excel when this runs. **3)** Call this process from a vbscript that opens a hidden Excel file in a separate instance of Excel.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman at the end using **Application.Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name()).Sheets('somesheet')**  will do it to do something with 'somesheet' sheet. What an ugly expression :-). By the way, in the the third point you mentionned, will this 
 block the user  to work with another Excel  file ?

Comment: @pascalsautot - the expression can be less ugly if you assign each objects to a variable (workbook, then sheet). In third point, it will not block users from using *a separate instance of Excel*. It may slow down processing on the CPU though, but that is true for the current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name()).Sheets('somesheet‌​') made it up
```

Thx @DarrenBartrup-Cook